# Printing a output (a function?) to a file?

Tags: python, function, output

I have a script in Python where I login into a Cisco device and want to print the output of a command to a file.

I've got the output all OK, but not sure how I go about printing it into a file.

Here's my code which logs in, prints the output I need, and logs out. Works well -- I know it isn't elegant :)

```
import pexpect

HOST = "172.17.1.1"
user = "username"
password = "password"

policymap = pexpect.spawn ('telnet '+HOST)
policymap.expect ('Username: ')
policymap.sendline (user)
policymap.expect ('Password: ')
policymap.sendline (password)
routerHostname = "switch1"
policymap.expect (routerHostname+'#')
policymap.sendline ('sh policy-map interface gi0/1\r')
print(policymap.readline())
policymap.expect (routerHostname+'#')
policymap.sendline ('exit\r')
print policymap.before
```

I tried adding a function and printing the output of the function to the file, but I think I may be on the wrong track here?

```
def cisco_output():
        print policymap.before

filename = "policymap.txt"
target = open(filename, 'w')
target.write(cisco_output)
target.close()
```

Comment: What Python version are you using? You use both `print` and `print()` which is unusual.

Comment: You should  use `with` to open your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `print` inside the function but `return` what you want to save. Then *call* the function by appending `()` to the function name.

```
def cisco_output():
    return policymap.before

filename = "policymap.txt"
target = open(filename, 'w')
target.write(cisco_output())
target.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("policymap.txt", "w") as f:
    print >>f, policymap.before
```

Comment: `with` is nice but the question was about printing the result of of *function*, not an object property.